# Laravel Redis - artisan cache:clear - Connection refused [unix:/path/.redis/redis.sock]

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I have configured Redis (using a socket) in the Laravel in my hosting server. Everything works fine (I have tested reading from cache, sessions etc.), I have one database for a cache and a second one for users sessions.
 However, when I run "php artisan cache:clear" it shows the error:
"In AbstractConnection.php line 155: Connection refused [unix:/path/.redis/redis.sock]".
This error also occures when I run any command which uses Redis, for example "php73 artisan cron:updateForeignPrices".

**.env**

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=/path/.redis/redis.sock
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=0
REDIS_CACHE_DB=0
REDIS_SESSION_DB=1
```

**config/database.php**

```
'redis' => [
    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),
    'cluster' => true,

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'predis'),
        'prefix' => Str::slug(env('APP_NAME'), '_').'_',
        'parameters' => ['password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null)],
    ],

    'default' => [
        'scheme' => 'unix',
        'path' => env('REDIS_HOST'),
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 0)
    ],

    'cache' => [
        'scheme' => 'unix',
        'path' => env('REDIS_HOST'),
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 0),
    ],

    'session' => [
        'scheme' => 'unix',
        'path' => env('REDIS_HOST'),
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_SESSION_DB', 1),
    ]
]
```

**Hosting provider's info about Redis (translated):**
Socket: /path-to-my-directory/.redis/redis.sock
User and password: (none)
Port: 0
RAM: 128 MB
Instruction on WordPress Litespeed:

1. In the „Host” field paste address from the panel, for example: /home/klient.dhosting.pl/dhtutorial/.redis/redis.sock
2. In the „Port” field remove a default value and type "0".
3. Leave "user" and "password" empty.

It seems like everything works correctly in a direct use of Redis, but not via console. Anyone has an idea how to fix it?

Thanks in advance, I have searched whole Internet.

Comment: If my answer does not help you, let me know more about your issue, so that I will be able to help you.

Comment: What Laravel version are you using? Do you have predis/predis dependency installed?

Comment: Sorry for a late answer. Check out my updated question (hosting provider info section).

Comment: Laravel version is 5.8, I'm using Predis.

Comment: @SentalPL `It seems like everything works correctly in a direct use of Redis, but not via console.`. What console? You mean the `redis-cli` command line or the execution of this `php artisan cache:clear`?

Comment: What also is the `direct use of Redis`? You mean that it is used by `Laravel` and creates cache and handles the sessions but you can't use it in command line via the commands `php artisan ...`?

Comment: I mean it's working in Controllers, but not in jobs - cron, console commands (yes, like "php artisan")..

Answer (score 1):

REDIS_HOST should point to the address where the Redis server is hosted whether it's hosted on a local machine or cloud service. somethings like below:

```
REDIS_HOST=12.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=password
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Comment: I'm using a socket, so when I change a path like just in localhost it shows the error "No such file or directory [unix:127.0.0.1]".

Answer (score 0):

set `REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1` or your host address

Comment: It's not working. Check my updated question (I added a section about configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following configuration.

**.env**

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_SCHEME=unix
REDIS_PATH=/path/.redis/redis.sock

REDIS_CACHE_DB=0
REDIS_SESSION_DB=1
```

**config.database.php**

```
'redis' => [
    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),
    'cluster' => true,

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'predis'),
        'prefix' => Str::slug(env('APP_NAME'), '_').'_',
        'parameters' => ['password' => null],
    ],

    'default' => [
        'scheme' => env('REDIS_SCHEME'),
        'path' => env('REDIS_PATH'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 0)
    ],

    'cache' => [
        'scheme' => env('REDIS_SCHEME'),
        'path' => env('REDIS_PATH'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 0),
    ],

    'session' => [
        'scheme' => env('REDIS_SCHEME'),
        'path' => env('REDIS_PATH'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_SESSION_DB', 1),
    ]
]
```

Comment: Didn't work :/ Anyway, nothing was changed there except removing 3 lines for each driver and typing "unix" scheme as the env variable.

Comment: @SentalPL try to also add `HOST`. Although i don't think it is needed. There is a good chance that `ACL` is used https://redis.io/topics/acl. Have you checked that no specific rules for specific users are set?